# Chemical potentials at triple point

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, phase-transition, chemical-potential, phase-diagram

> How to prove that chemical potential of each phase at triple point are equal?

My attempt: At phase transition, $P$ and $T$ are constant and using $dG=0$(Gibbs free energy at minimum) at equilibrium  gives
$$\mu_1dN_1 + \mu_2dN_2 + \mu_3dN_3= 0$$
$dN_1 + dN_2 + dN_3 =0$ if we assume no additional substance is being added. Using this, we'll have
$$(\mu_2 - \mu_1)dN_2 +  (\mu_3 - \mu_1)dN_3 =0).$$

I am stuck here. How to prove from here that
$$\mu_1 =\mu_2 =\mu_3~?$$

Comment: I am not sure that you can prove that. The fact that the phases coexist in stability for $P$ and $T$ invariable, means that the Gibbs potential (function of $P$,$T$,($\mu_1,\mu_2,\mu_3$) does not change, as you shown. And it only means the migration of particles between phases is equilibrated, thus the energies related to this migration ($\mu_1,\mu_2,\mu_3$) are equal. In other words, if one of them were lower, all the particles would go to this phase and the system would collapse into only one phase.

Comment: Mass conservation will only get the ratio of the potentials but if you move an infinitesimal amount away from the triple point onto one of the three 2-phase coexistence curves, say $ik$ you will have $\mu_i=\mu_k$. So if you assume continuity of the chemical potential their equality is assured at the triple point.

Comment: @user31748 your answer is convincing. Thanks!

Comment: Does the fact that the 3 phases are in equilibrium help?

Answer (score 2):

The answer depends on the conceptual understanding of the formulas, more than on algebraic manipulations.
The final formula,
$$(\mu_2 - \mu_1)dN_2 +  (\mu_3 - \mu_1)dN_3 =0)$$
should hold for all possible changes of the two independent variables $N_2$ and $N_3$. This implies
$$\begin{align}
\mu_2 &= \mu_1  \\
\mu_3 &= \mu_1 \end{align}$$